# Weird issue with NSWindowController and ARC

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

**OK, here's a weird situation I'm facing :**

- I've got an `NSWindowController` subclass, a window in `myMainWindow.xib` and the `AppDelegate.m` invoking the `NSWindowController` like this :

  ```
  myWindowController* controller = [[myWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"myMainWindow"];
  [controller showWindow:self];
  ```

**Now here's what :**

- When ARC is set to `NO`, then the app runs fine and the windows shows up ok, too.
- When I set ARC to `YES` - immediately after I set it (and for JUST 1 run) - it shows a bunch of errors :

> Feb 17 16:35:45 DrKameleons-iMac.local MyApp[16903] :
>   kCGErrorIllegalArgument: _CGSFindSharedWindow: WID 2409 Feb 17
>   16:35:45 DrKameleons-iMac.local MyApp[16903] : kCGErrorFailure:
>   Set a breakpoint @ CGErrorBreakpoint() to catch errors as they are
>   logged. Feb 17 16:35:45 DrKameleons-iMac.local MyApp[16903] :
>   kCGErrorIllegalArgument: CGSOrderFrontConditionally: Invalid window

And the window does *not* show up.

Now if I try rerunning the app (without changing anything, ARC is still ON) the window still doesn't show up. But there is no error at all. :S

What is going on? Any ideas on how to fix this (and make the window appear)?

---

**HINTS :**

- Running on Mac OS X 10.7.5
- Xcode version : 4.5.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when ARC is on, the LOCAL controller is released right after its showWindow call! but as windows are deferred, the window isn't even there yet -- and even it were, it would be 'controller-less'
**the Window does NOT retain its controller :) only vice-versa**

the fix is to remember a reference to the controller Until your appDelegate is deallocated/until you quit

```
@implementation AppDelegate {
    myWindowController* _controller;
}

...
_controller = [[myWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"myMainWindow"];
[_controller showWindow:self];
```

---

your code works without arc because no release of controller happens and it just leaks! ARC does add a release call though (as it correctly sees controller is no longer used)

Comment: OK. You're my hero. Honestly. You can't imagine how much time of head-to-wall... contact you've saved me. Really. Thanks A LOT, mate! ;-)

Comment: :D I ran into the same issue when I first used ARC. But now I love ARC :)

Comment: Well, it's actually my (real) first time with ARC too. And the thing is, I got ARC working (finally), but not the initial thing that got me to seek for ARC's help... (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919248/objects-not-successfully-released-memory-management)